# How to implement Newton's method iteratively to estimate roots

Tags: python, newtons-method

User inputs a number, to which the code should estimate the cubed root of the number for a certain number of iterations (defined by N) or until the change in root estimations becomes small enough (at your discretion).

Started with initial approximation (x_initial) being 1 and running it through formula to obtain next iteration of X. Seems to get reasonable answer but beyond that can't seem to fathom what to do.

```
print('Enter number for cubed root:')
y=int(input())
x_initial=1
n=0

while n <= 50:
    x_new=1/3*(2*(x_initial) + y/(x_initial**2))
    print(x_new)
    n=n+1

    x_new=1/3*(2*(x_new) + y/(x_new**2))
    print(x_new)
    n=n+1
```

Estimation just alternates between two different values. Short of defining a new X equation after each iteration I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: Have it working for the number of iterations, however, after an amount of iterations the estimation stays the same (essentially solved). How would I code a break when the difference in iterations is 0 (or very small)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be that you reset x_new to be based on x_initial at the beginning of each loop. I will collapse both into a single variable x:

```
y = int(input('Enter number for cubed root:'))
x = 1
n = 50

for _ in range(n):
    x = 1/3 * (2*x + y/(x**2))
    print(x)
```

I've also made your code a bit more Pythonic in a few spots to aid readability.

Comment: I think there has to be an initial x value set otherwise a ZeroDivisionError is given back?

Comment: This seemed to do the trick, thanks for the help! Was much simpler than I was trying to make it in the end :) 
'y = int(input('Enter number for cubed root:'))
x = 1
N = 0

while N < 50:
    x = 1/3*(2*(x) + y/(x**2))
    print(x)
    N = N+1'

Answer (score 0):

Let f be a symbolic function representing the equation in question, dF being the symbolic equation representing the derivative of f, x0 starting value, epsilon (ending condition to exist the function when you are close enough to the root), and max_iter (how many iterations you want to run). This is better than your method because it works for any root as long as you write the appropriate derivative.

```
def newtons_method(f,Df,x0,epsilon,max_iter):
    xn = x0
    for n in range(0,max_iter):
        fxn = f(xn)
        if abs(fxn) < epsilon:
            print('Found solution after',n,'iterations.')
            return xn
        Dfxn = Df(xn)
        if Dfxn == 0:
            print('Zero derivative. No solution found.')
            return None
        xn = xn - fxn/Dfxn
    print('Exceeded maximum iterations. No solution found.')
    return None
```

Example Usage:

```
f = lambda x: x**4 - x**3 - 1
Df = lambda x: 4*x**3 - 3*x
approx = newtons_method(f,Df,1,1e-10,10)
print(approx)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why it's so complicated in your case and others but I tested this and it works simply:

```
def cubenewton(num, ini=1, iters=50):
    for i in range(iters):
        ini = ini - (ini**3 - num)/float(3*ini**2)
    return ini

>>> cubenewton(30) # I tried values from -100 to 100 and all works fine. works for 0 as well.
3.107232505953859
```